# How to change the default font used for creating buttons/labels?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am making many buttons and labels for my app, and it is very frustrating to have to change the font, size, colour etc. for each and every one.  I know I could draw them in code, but can you change the defaults in Interface Builder?

Comment: it is just the IDE, apologies for not making my question clearer

Comment: Please modify the tags to include the language and platform you're targeting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a custom subclass of UIButton and write code in it's init method that sets the custom properties you want. Let's call your custom button MyFontsButton.

Then, in IB, create a button, then go to the identity inspector and change the button's class from UIButton to MyFontsButton.

The button will automatically use the attributes you set up in your init method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Duncan. I think I recognise your photo from another website, so I'm honoured!  I've tried -(id) init {self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:20] return self;} but this hasn't worked when subclassing. Any help?  Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, just select all of them with your mouse in the xib file and edit in the "Attributes inspector".

Answer (score 3):

You could duplicate a control in IB with `cmd+D`. That way the preferences carry over.